# Finding STC module using CMake - C++/wxWidgets

Tags: c++, build, cmake, wxwidgets, scintilla

It looks like `FindwxWidgets.CMake` can't find `stc` module from `contrib`. I have the following in my `CMakeList` file.

```
find_package(wxWidgets COMPONENTS core base stc REQUIRED)
```

This is failing with message, can't find wxWidget. If I remove `stc` from it, all works. How can I address this issue?

I am using `CMake2.8` on Windows 7 and `wxWidgets 2.8.11`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [bug tracker](http://www.cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=8954) finding contrib modules is not supported under Windows. There is a patch attached to that issue that might help you. As of wxWidgets 2.9 the stc library was moved into the core feature set of wxWidgets and so is supported in recent versions of CMake.